# Disable background when popup get activated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have left navigation menu. The code is below -

```
<div id="pdAppSidenav" class="sidenav show-xs hidden-lg" style="display:none">
  <a href="#">Life Insurance</a>


    <section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">

        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture cd-picture-active">
            </div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-content cd-timeline-content-active">
                <h4>Quote</h4>
            </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
            </div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-content">
                <h4>Apply</h4>
            </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
            </div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-content">
                <h4>Approve</h4>
            </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

        <div class="cd-timeline-block">
            <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
            </div>
            <div class="cd-timeline-content">
                <h4>Pay</h4>
            </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
        </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

    </section> <!-- cd-timeline -->

    <div class="pd-content-bottom">
                <h3>XXXXXXX</h3>
                <p>XXXXX</p>
    </div> 

</div>
```

This popup toggles (opens and closes) when I click on the following icon -

```
<div id="hamburgerIconId" class="hamburgerIcon"></div>
```

The JS for the following is -

```
function leftnav() {
  var collapse_sidebar_modal = document.getElementById('pdAppSidenav');
  var  collapse_sidebar_icon = document.getElementById("hamburgerIconId");
    console.log(collapse_sidebar_modal);
    var isOpen="false"
        collapse_sidebar_icon.onclick = function() { 
            if(isOpen==="false"){
                collapse_sidebar_modal.style.display = "block";
            collapse_sidebar_modal.style.width = "250px";
                isOpen="true";
            }
            else{
                collapse_sidebar_modal.style.display = "none";
            collapse_sidebar_modal.style.width = "0px";
                isOpen  = "false";
            }
        }
}
```

Everything works perfectly. I want to disable the background so that the user cannot interact with the background elements when this popup opens. How do I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: fixed position element with same size as viewport and a "z index" that is "above" the content but "below" the active content is one way

Comment: share your code in a snippet or fiddler to understand better.